# Why does "\t" in python make output automatically align to the left?

Tags: python, tabs, alignment

In my homework I was told to make a power table with 5 rows and 10 columns. Value of the power table at row `i`, column `j` is `j^i` and the column should be spaced with a tab.

```py
row = 5
column = 10

i = 1
while i <= row:
    j = 1
    while j <= column:
        print(j ** i, end='\t')
        j += 1
    print("")
    i += 1
```

And here is the output:

[image]

This works very well, but I don't understand why every column is automatically aligned to the left. Shouldn't `'\t'` create a tab that has the same length of 4 spaces every time? For example, the spaces in the last 2 columns between "9 and 10" and "59049 and 100000" are apparently not equal. Why is that?

Comment: If you search in your browser for "Python output tab", you'll find references that can explain this much better than we can manage here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's how it's supposed to work.

A tab character, when printed to a terminal, becomes enough spaces to space up to the next multiple of 8*. (This makes it useful for making **tab**les.)

So if you print pairs of numbers separated by tabs, you get:

```
        | <-- 8 characters is here
1       23456
12      3456
123     456
1234    56
```

etc. But you can't see this effect when you're using them to indent, because when there's nothing in front of them they all come out full width, so you get:

```
        | <-- 8 characters is here
non-indented stuff
        indented stuff
```

* Tab size is configurable in many text editors, but generally not in terminals, where you get the traditional default of 8.